# Android Material Design widget parent for Switch

Tags: android, material-design

Does anyone know what the widget parent is for a Material Design Switch?  For example, the Material Design widget parent for Seekbar is:

```
<style name="FooSeekbar" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.SeekBar"></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include the appcompat v7 library, this is the xml code you use to define such a Switch

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
android:id="@+id/dev_switch_show_dev_only"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

I didn't found any parent name, so you can add the custom style to your view by using android:style

Comment: I have tried to use SwitchCompat but when I do, no widget is displayed.  And yes, I do have 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0' in my build gradle file.

Comment: @PerryHoekstra There is an update available for the appcompat v7: use  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

Comment: Yes, that is true.  However, when I tried to upgrade to v7:23.0.0, I receive a: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3 on the latest version of Android Studio v 1.3.1  So, for now, I am not moving off of v7:22.2.1

Comment: What version of build tools are you using?

Comment: buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

Comment: Try updating the Java JDK to version 1.8.0_25. You are using an outdated version of java

Comment: Ummm, no. JDK 1.7.0.79 is the latest/greatest of the JDK 7 line so it is not outdated and in addition, the Android Studio installation docs have not changed their sentence: "JDK 7 is required when developing for Android 5.0 and higher." and I am not going to introduce possible problems to solve this issue by moving to Java 8 at this time.

Comment: @PerryHoekstra I think that that might solve the issue. But I'm using version 1.8.0_25, so there is a newer version available. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html